# Amplify Deployment for ReactNative (+Expo) Succeeded, but FrontEnd build steps (apparently) not run

Tags: react-native, deployment, expo, aws-amplify

I checked the logs for the deployment and noticed that nothing seems to have been run as part of the frontend build stage, even though my build settings are telling it to run `npx expo export:web`. As a result, I get a 404 when trying to access the url.

My build settings are:

```yaml
version: 1
applications:
    -
        backend:
            phases:
                build:
                    commands: ['nvm use 18', 'npm ci', 'npx amplify pipeline-deploy --branch $AWS_BRANCH --app-id $AWS_APP_ID']
        frontend:
            phases:
                build:
                    commands: []
            artifacts:
                baseDirectory: /
                files:
                    - '**/*'
            cache:
                paths: []
        appRoot: modules/app
frontend:
    phases:
        build:
            commands:
                - 'npx expo export:web'
    artifacts:
        baseDirectory: web-build
```

Here are the logs for what's going on.

```
(...)
2023-12-06T22:32:50.466Z [INFO]:
2023-12-06T22:32:53.892Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: build
## Completed Backend Build
2023-12-06T22:32:53.895Z [INFO]: ## Starting Frontend Build
# Starting phase: build
# Completed phase: build
## Completed Frontend Build
2023-12-06T22:32:53.988Z [INFO]: ## Build completed successfully
2023-12-06T22:32:53.991Z [INFO]: # Starting caching...
2023-12-06T22:32:53.991Z [INFO]: Nothing to cache
2023-12-06T22:32:53.991Z [INFO]: # Caching completed
2023-12-06T22:32:53.993Z [INFO]: # No custom headers found.
2023-12-06T22:32:54.008Z [WARNING]: !! No index.html detected in deploy folder: /codebuild/output/src1323226312/src/appname/modules/app/
2023-12-06T22:32:54.008Z [INFO]: # Starting build artifact upload process...
2023-12-06T22:33:18.445Z [INFO]: # Uploading build artifact '__artifacts.zip'...
2023-12-06T22:33:18.454Z [INFO]: # Uploading build artifact '__artifactsHash.zip'...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

It turns out that the issue was related to (a) the fact that I'm working on a "mono-repo" design and (b) the amplitude.yml generated by the AWS Management Console for Amplify wasn't perfect.

By moving the `frontend` build configuration under my `application`, the build started working correctly and the 404 error was gone.

## The bug

The settings for the frontend build were not set under my `application` and the front end build commands for my application was empty.  Check below the before and after to see what the problem was, and how it got fixed.

**Before**

```
version: 1
applications:
    -
        appRoot: modules/app
        backend:
            (...)
        frontend:
            phases:
                build:
                    commands: []
            artifacts:
                baseDirectory: /
                files:
                    - '**/*'
            cache:
                paths: []
frontend:
    phases:
        build:
            commands:
                - 'npx expo export:web'
    artifacts:
        baseDirectory: web-build
```

**After (fixed the problem)**

```
version: 1
applications:
    - appRoot: modules/app
      backend:
          (...)
      frontend:
          phases:
              build:
                  commands:
                      - "npx expo export:web"
          artifacts:
              baseDirectory: web-build
              files:
                  - "**/*"
          cache:
              paths: []
```

## Conclusion

If you are using mono-repo, make sure that your frontend configuration falls into the right `application`